# flowpayer not working on android device. (Flash version 10,1 or greater is required)

Tags: javascript, android, html, flash, flowplayer

I am using flowplayer 3.2.12 version.

Everything works great on all browser, devices except android devices.

When testing on android device, i get a message and the player does not work:

```
"**Flash version 10, 1 or greater is required**

**You have no flash plugin installed**

**Click here to download latest version**"
```

This message appears on all the android device and I have been referring all the flowplayer related documents, but in vein.

As per this [flowplayer documentation](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html#flowplayer-specific-flash-properties) , i tried setting xpressInstall to null which did not work either.

For example you can [check this video on an android device](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/standalone/toolbox/flashembed/flowplayer.html)

http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/standalone/toolbox/flashembed/flowplayer.html

Has anyone had luck with any solution for this flowplayer - android issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: html5 version of flowplayer ? @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix for the issue with android devices and it is tested, works perfectly fine on all devices.

The key thing is to add the **android/i navigator.userAgent** after set up script for flowplayer:

```
ipad({simulateiDevice: /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)});
```

Setup with the device fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $f("player", {
            src: "/PATH/TO/FLOWPLAYER/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.10.swf",
            wmode: 'opaque'
        }, {
            key: '#$09ce03a35b17ee17229'
        }).ipad({ simulateiDevice: true, controls: false });
    }
    else {
        $f("player", {
            src: "/PATH/TO/FLOWPLAYER/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.10.swf",
            wmode: 'opaque'
        }, {
            key: '#$09ce03a35b17ee17229'
        }).ipad({simulateiDevice: /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)});

});
```